# How to get values from AJAX call into variables for multiple selection Person and Group fields?

Tags: jquery, sharepoint-rest-api, person

The following works great to retrieve multiple selection Person and Group fields:

```
url: xurl+"/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('"+xlist+"')/items/getById('+xid+')?$select=Approvers/Name,Reviewers/Name,Informed/Name&$expand=Approvers,Reviewers,Informed"
```

Then what? I want to set the retrieved values in a variable or array...

```
var x=data.d.Name; // doesn't work, even for single value entries
```

and then proceed to set a form field with the retrieved value(s)...

```
$("input[title='Approvers']").val(x); // need proper field type, not input
```

Suggestions? Looking at the request in browser I can see all the properties I want, just can't pull them out and put them in variables.

**UPDATE**

The next step after my successful call should check to see if any users are defined as Approvers before performing any related actions. Below works for a single user but not if multiple users are defined in in multi-person column.

```
if (data.d.Approvers != undefined) {
```

nor this

```
if (data.d.Approvers.results.length>0 {
```

nor this

```
$.each(data.d.Approvers.results, function (index, item) {console.log("hello");});
```

console log error for multi:

```
console.log(data.d.results);
```

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read... property 'Approvers' of undefined
 at Object.success...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The returned data is a collection:

```
data.d.Approvers.results.length
```

To get the first item:

```
data.d.Approvers.results[0]
```

Or the first user's name:

```
data.d.Approvers.results[0].Name
```

I have a REST tester for SharePoint that's useful for testing these kinds of things.
https://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.com/2017/04/a-sharepoint-rest-api-tester-with-ajax.html
https://github.com/microsmith/SharePointRESTtester

Comment: These are producing errors when more than one person is in the Approvers column. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: The methods you listed work, the specific list item with multiple ppl I was using for testing was creating problems for some reason. When I used a different list item with multiple ppl this worked. Weird. Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the `results` array is not present if there are no users in the field, and it is present if there are one or more users.  So you could just do:

```
// if results is not present on Approvers it will be undefined, which
// evaluates falsy, so it won't ever enter if if block if it's not there

if (data.d.Approvers.results) {
    data.d.Approvers.results.forEach(function (approver) {
        // do something with the approver here
        console.log(approver.Name);
    }
}
```

Here's a blog post I found that explains a bit about [what evaluates truthy and falsy](http://adripofjavascript.com/blog/drips/truthy-and-falsy-values-in-javascript.html).

Comment: With this code, if Approvers column has more than one person in it I get the following error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Approvers' of undefined
 at Object.success...

Comment: The methods you listed work, the specific list item with multiple ppl I was using for testing was creating problems for some reason. When I used a different list item with multiple ppl this worked. Weird. Thanks for your advice.